# How can I add a CASE statement in a WHERE clause?

Tags: views, hooks, 9

I need to add a WHERE clause to the query altered by a `hook_views_query_alter()` implementation. The WHERE clause needs to contain the following CASE statement.

```php
$sql = "(CASE WHEN node_field_data.type IN ('course', 'events') AND ((node__field_event_start_date.field_event_start_date_value > today) OR (node__field_event_start_time.field_event_start_time_value > 0 AND node__field_event_start_time.field_event_start_time_value > current_timestamp)) THEN 1 WHEN node_field_data.type = 'insight' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1";

$query->addWhere(2, $sql, 1, '=');
```

I tried to use `addWhere()`, but it removes all the spaces from the condition and causes the following error.

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '."field_event_start_time_value0ANDnode__field_event_start_time"."field_event_sta' at line 6

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Resolved it by adding additional AND OR condition groups. Sharing this in case anyone needs it in future.

```
    $start_date_configuration = [
      'table' => 'node__field_event_start_date',
      'field' => 'entity_id',
      'left_table' => 'node_field_data',
      'left_field' => 'nid',
      'operator' => '=',
    ];
    $join = Views::pluginManager('join')->createInstance('standard', $start_date_configuration);
    $query->addRelationship('node__field_event_start_date', $join, 'node_field_data');

    $start_time_configuration = [
      'table' => 'node__field_event_start_time',
      'field' => 'entity_id',
      'left_table' => 'node_field_data',
      'left_field' => 'nid',
      'operator' => '=',
    ];
    $join = Views::pluginManager('join')->createInstance('standard', $start_time_configuration);
    $query->addRelationship('node__field_event_start_time', $join, 'node_field_data');

    $current_timestamp = (new DrupalDateTime())->getTimestamp();

    $query->setWhereGroup('OR', 3);
    $query->addWhere(3, 'node_field_data.type', 'insight');
    $query->addWhere(3, (
      $query->getConnection()->condition('AND'))
      ->condition('node_field_data.type', ['course', 'events'], 'IN')
      ->condition(
        $query->getConnection()->condition('OR')
          ->condition('node__field_event_start_date.field_event_start_date_value', date('Y-m-d'), '>=')
          ->condition(
          $query->getConnection()->condition('AND')
            ->condition('node__field_event_start_date.field_event_start_date_value', NULL, 'IS NULL')
            ->condition('node__field_event_start_time.field_event_start_time_value', $current_timestamp, '>=')
        )
      )
    );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with `$query->addWhereExpression()`.
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21query%21Sql.php/9
For example:
`$query->addWhereExpression($group, 'Expression with CASE', [$arguments]);`